# Split string confusion

Tags: python, string, split

I need to split a string:

Example:

```
str = 'mink.microctr.fit.edu - - [21/Jun/2000:20:21:36 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1786'
```

From the above string I need to extract `"21/Jun/2000"`.

Using:

```
str.rstrip().split()[3]
```

the output is `"[21/Jun/2000"`.

Any help on how to go about this?

Comment: The way you have typed this into your post it will not be a valid python string. However if you make the first and last character a `'` instead of `"` characters then it is a valid string. Do you know why?

Comment: Don't name a variable `str`.  It overrides the built-in.

Comment: How about `str.split(':')[0].split('[')[1]` ?

Comment: You may want to look into using a regular expression.  While you can use split, it may break easily if anything unexpected sneaks in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
str.split()[3][1:].split(':')[0]
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd use regular expressions:

```
>>> import re
>>> r = 'mink.microctr.fit.edu - - [21/Jun/2000:20:21:36 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1786'
>>> print re.search(r'\[(.*?):', r).group(1)
21/Jun/2000
```

Also don't name strings `str`, it will override the built-in type

Comment: "I'd use regular expressions" -- now you have 2 problems! (I kid.)

Answer (score 0):

You can just add `[1:]`:

```
str.rstrip().split()[3][1:]
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use split or can you also get a substring?  If the format always looks like that, then try this:

```
str.strip().split()[3][1:]
```

Let's break this down: `str.strip()` strips off all of the whitespace.  Then you use `split()` which splits on any whitespace.  That's what you have so far.  Now, `str[1:]` says "take the substring starting at the second character in the string until the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex like so :

```
(\d{2}/[A-Za-z]{3}/\d{4})
```

Read this about using [regex with python](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/systems-programming/regular-expressions-in-python/), if you have never done it.

Comment: @Johan I added a link to explain regex usage in Python. However I believe everything necessary to solve the problem was in the answer if the person is willing to simply google "regex" or "regex python".